# Ehache Big Cache Elements Not Expiring

Tags: java, ehcache, ehcache-bigmemory

I have set both timeToIdle and timeToLive properties on my cache. They are set to 10 minutes and 1 hour respectively.

Every 5 minutes, I have a cron job that calls `getKeysWithExpiryCheck()` to do some processing on the elements in the cache. I have also registered a cache listener to perform a process when an element is expired or is evicted.

What I am finding is that elements are only removed from the cache when the cache becomes full - despite calling `getKeysWithExpiryCheck`. Because I am using a Terrocota Big Memory Cache (4.0.4), this invariably locks up my system as the cache then expires (and performs a process on) millions of entries that should have been processed within 5 minutes of the TTL or TTI.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that an element is not evicted until it has expired **and** has been accessed. Take a look at what the [Documentation](http://ehcache.org/documentation/configuration/data-life#30343) has to say:

> If an entry expires but is not accessed, and no resource constraints force eviction, then the expired entry remains in place.

Unfortunately while calling getKeysWithExpiryCheck() will only return you keys that have not expired, it will not force eviction of the expired elements. Still in this case, a large number of elements being evicted at once shouldn't lock up your system. Have you taken thread dumps or looked at your GC logs when your system locks up to verify what is slowing everything down?